# How do I remove links from a workbook linked to another

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet(Questions) in a workbook(Rating) that has a button at the bottom of the Questions sheet that copies sheet 2(quote) from the Rating workbook and pastes it in a new workbook that is named according to the quote number and then saved.

Here is that code:

```
Sub GetQuote()
    Range("AK548").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AK549").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Dim Output As Workbook
    Dim FileName As String

    Set Output = Workbooks.Add
    FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Questions").Range("AK545").Value & ".xls"
    Output.SaveAs FileName

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Output.Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Copy Before:=Output.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Output.Worksheets(1).Name = "Sheet1"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Output.Protect Password:="12345"
    Output.Save
End Sub
```

Now I intend on removing the links that now exsist between this new copy and the Quote sheet and only leave the values. How would I do this?

I have found this code that should delete the links that exsist:

```
Dim Cell As Range, FirstAddress As String, Temp As String
    'delete all links from selected cells
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Selection
        Set Cell = .Find("=*!", LookIn:=xlFormulas, searchorder:=xlByRows, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True)
        On Error GoTo Finish
        FirstAddress = Cell.Address
        Do
            Temp = Cell
            Cell.ClearContents
            Cell = Temp
            Set Cell = .FindNext(Cell)
        Loop Until Cell Is Nothing Or Cell.Address = FirstAddress
    End With
Finish:
```

All I have done extra is put this code in below the code that Names and copies the sheet and that did not work?

So now how would I combine these two pieces of code so that everything gets copied and the links removed?

Answer (score 6):

I had existing workbooks that had external links that i needed to remove from the workbooks and then re save them.

This worked for me:

```
Sub BreakExternalLinks()
'PURPOSE: Breaks all external links that would show up in Excel's "Edit Links" Dialog Box
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/The-Code-Vault

Dim ExternalLinksArray As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim x As Long

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

'Create an Array of all External Links stored in Workbook
  ExternalLinksArray = wb.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)

'if the array is not empty the loop Through each External Link in ActiveWorkbook and Break it
 If IsEmpty(ExternalLinksArray) = False then
     For x = 1 To UBound(ExternalLinksArray )
        wb.BreakLink Name:=ExternalLinksArray (x), Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
      Next x
end if

End Sub
```

Comment: was looking for `.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)`. ty!

Comment: In my experience, this doesn't *look* like it works.  But when you close your workbook and then re-open it, you'll see that the links really have been removed.

Answer (score 4):

This piece of code kills all connections in the active workbook... apologies, but can't remember where I got it.

```
    'Kill Connections
    If ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(1).Delete
        Next i
    Else
    End If
```

Tested with your code, this seems to work:

```
    Dim Output As Workbook
Dim FileName As String

Set Output = Workbooks.Add
FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Questions").Range("A1").Value & ".xls"
Output.SaveAs FileName

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Output.Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Copy Before:=Output.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Output.Worksheets(1).Name = "Sheet1"

Output.Worksheets(1).Select
If ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(1).Delete
    Next i
Else
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Output.Protect Password:="12345"
Output.Save
```

Comment: Are you selecting the workbook you want to remove the connections on before running this? Would suggest running before saving and adding a password.

Comment: Output.Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Copy Before:=Output.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Output.Worksheets(1).Name = "Sheet1"                              Add this?>>>>Output.Worksheets("Sheet1").Select                                    Hopefully this works

Comment: It `says count = 0` if I debug

Comment: Tested it with the code amended to my answer.Taking a look at your code, there doesn't seem to be any connections made. Perhaps there is a different problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31933/discussion-between-mike-barnes-and-maus)

Comment: Could it be, that you mixed up "ThisWorkbook" and "ActiveWorkbook"? "ThisWorkbook" references the workbook the macro is in. "ActiveWorkbok" is the workbook you are seeing.

Comment: *Sorry Chat is blocked on my DNS :(

Comment: In your code should "ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(1).Delete" be "ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(i).Delete" instead or does the next connection in the list become 1 after you delete item 1?

Comment: Think you just nailed the problem. I have since moved over to PowerQuery... this made life much better from a security perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would help, if you don't use the actual copy & paste functions. If you only need the values of the cells, then change your macro to

```
Sub GetQuote()
    Range("AK548").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AK549").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Dim Output As Workbook
    Dim FileName As String

    Set Output = Workbooks.Add
    FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Questions").Range("AK545").Value & ".xls"
    Output.SaveAs FileName

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim v, r As Long, c As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
        r = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        c = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
        v = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(r, c))
    End With
    With Output.Worksheets(1)
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(r, c)) = v
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Output.Protect Password:="12345"
    Output.Save
End Sub
```

This copies the values of your origin sheet to the new workbook sheet, without any links.

P.S.: Don't mix up **ThisWorkbook** and **ActiveWorkbook**. `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook where the macro is located (, but not necessarily the active workbook). `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook, you see at that time.