# Sharing SQL Backed Excel Sheets outside of network

Tags: sql, excel, vba

We have an Excel workbook that contains some connections to a SQL database on the back end. We'd like to easily send this to people who

1. don't have read access to the SQL database, or
2. are outside of the trusted network.

I know there are some multi-step processes or macros that could be written to do this, but is there a quicker way that can be taught to less technical people?

I could have sworn there was a way to save data only or something of that nature, but I cannot find it.

Comment: You would have to import the data into the spreadsheet, making it no longer connected to the actual database. That's pretty simple to do if that is what you are asking, but then if the database changes, the spreadsheet will no longer update.

Comment: Hi,   Yes.  This is what I’m looking for.  The data is point in time (a report) and doesn’t need to update.    We have them copying and pasting “values” now, but it’s kind of a kluge.   

I was going to write a macro to do that, but it introduces more complexity.

Comment: Although this code seems to apply to 2 linked workbooks, I think it will work with a linked database as well... give it a try? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165280/how-do-i-remove-links-from-a-workbook-linked-to-another

Comment: Thanks braX.   I appreciate it.   I actually already have a macro that copies the data and pastes back as values.   

I was hoping that there was still a way to remove connections on save or something like that and only save static data.   Earlier versions of Excel actually had this, but it seems to have been removed.